# Ruby on Rails: Records not being added

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an iPhone client that is supposed to add records to a Heroku app I made. The problem is no records are being added.

This is my rails code:

```
   Bathroom.Create(name =>params[:name],
                    :bathroomtype =>params[:bathroomtype],
                    :street =>params[:street],
                    :city =>params[:city],
                    :state =>params[:state],
                   :country =>params[:country],
                    :postal =>params[:postal],
                    :lat =>params[:lat],
                    :lon =>params[:lon],
                    :access =>params[:access], 
                    :directions =>params[:directions],
                    :comment =>params[:comment],
                    :avail =>params[:avail] )
                    render :nothing => true
```

Earlier in my testing, it seemed to work on local server. That makes me think I'm not hitting the production database but I'm not sure how to set that up?

After testing locally, I did a heroku db:push which pushed the database but I'm still not sure that I'm hitting the right thing. No records are being created.

This is my database.yml

development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

So, I'm confused about whether the create code is correct? If so, then why are my entries not showing up in the database?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things leap out at me, `name` is a bare word instead of a symbol (missing the leading colon), and `Create` should be `create`. For debugging, you can check to see if validations have failed by looking at `Bathroom.create(params).errors.full_messages`. You can also say "if save fails, raise exception" by using `create!` instead of `create`, and then checking your logs for what died.